# How can I set the scale with alphabet on chartjs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, chart.js

I am currently developing the Ruby on Rails app and hoping to embed radar chart using the scale from alphabet A to G and S instead of numbers, G as the lowest grade(min) and S as the best grade(max).
G < F < E < D < C < B < A < S

The chartjs official document shows only numbers for the data and also the scale min and max setting.

Is there any method to activate alphabet scale and data instead of numbers??

```
options = {
    scale: {
        angleLines: {
            display: false
        },
        ticks: {
            suggestedMin: 50,
            suggestedMax: 100
        }
    }
};
```

link to the document is here...
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/radar.html

highly appreciated any advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beta of version 3 has an example online with this: https://www.chartjs.org/samples/master/scales/non-numeric-y.html